# Minifilter Driver : Specifying Altitude leads to BSOD

Tags: filter-driver

I'm trying to build a minifilter driver to log all IRPs. Logging takes place in the driver itself (using **FltCreateFile()**, **FltWriteFile()**...).

Without specifying an altitude in the .inf file, the minifilter loads but does not attach to any volume. Manually attaching using **fltmc attach** also fails (Attach failed : incorrect parameter).

When specifying an altitude, **fltmc load filter** leads to BSOD.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the INF driver installation file. Making sure the **Strings** section of the **INF file** is correct (no typos) may help.

Creating a new Minifilter driver project solved the problem for me.